# Options to insert issues into JIRA from an external source

Tags: jira

We use an external service to gather errors that happen in the Front-End code of our web application. For bug tracking in general, we use JIRA. We do have set up so that it's possible to insert an issue into JIRA by sending an e-mail. However, the external service does not have the option to send an e-mail for new errors.

The external service does have the ability to use WebHooks but from my research I only found that you can only use JIRA as the source of a WebHook notification to some remote system. If it would be possible to have that the other way around then we would be able to take advantage of that.

The only thing that comes to mind is to have a point to which the external service will send notifications of new errors and have that point send an e-mail to our JIRA. Question: does anybody know of some other options what can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party service to accomplish this. Zapier has a direct to jira option which translates webhooks into issues.

1. Error is generated on your webpage and sent to your external service
2. External service sends a webhook to Zapier
3. Zapier gathers the data from the webhook and creates a JIRA Issue via api.

This is assuming that your external service sends the error's data inside the webhook. Then zapier will extract that data and put it into the body of the email. Zapier is free up to 100 webhooks a month.

Here is the zap to use:
https://zapier.com/app/editor/1314173